# TypeScript inheritence - Why I am not getting a type error when parameter is a sibling sub-class?

Tags: inheritance, typescript

Given this code, which can be tried here:

```
export abstract class AbstractSanitizedString {    
    constructor(private s: string) {
    }    
}

export class PersonNickname extends AbstractSanitizedString {
    constructor(label: string) {
        super(label + " Smith");
    }    
}

export class AlphaNumericString extends AbstractSanitizedString {
    constructor(s: string) {
        super(s);
    }
}

export class Person {    
    constructor(private name: PersonNickname) {
    }    
}

new Person(new AlphaNumericString("John"));
```

([the code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20AbstractSanitizedString%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20s%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20PersonNickname%20extends%20AbstractSanitizedString%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(label%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(label%20%2B%20%22%20Smith%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20AlphaNumericString%20extends%20AbstractSanitizedString%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(s%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(s)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Person%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20name%3A%20PersonNickname)%20%7B%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Person(new%20AlphaNumericString(%22John%22))%3B))

I expected a compilation error here, since I am sending in a `AlphaNumericString`, while I defined it should only take in an `PersonNickname`.

Is this correct?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html:  "The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that `x` is compatible with `y` if `y` has at least the same members as `x`"

Comment: But they might have different implementations, right? Anyway to turn this off, as far as you know? Or I have to break the inheritance alltogether?

Comment: No way to turn it off, this is a core part of Typescript's inheritance model.  Basically, if two objects have the same "shape", they're the same type of object.  The only way (AFAIK) to change this is to give each type a member that the other type does not have.

Comment: you will need to add a member that is unique to the more derived class